# plot bar chart with line chart using plot_date and bar function

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are two subplot

1. Linechart with date ( no issue )
2. Bar chart with date ( issue )

I am trying to create a barchart with date along x-axis in subplot.
Below is the code

```
     days = pd.to_datetime(df['indx'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
     RSI_14 = df['RSI_14']
     ATR_14 = df['ATR_14']
     fig5 = plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=200)
     ax1 = fig5.add_subplot(211)
     ax2 = fig5.add_subplot(212)
     ax1.plot_date(x=days, y=RSI_14,fmt="r-",label="ROC_7")
     ax2.bar(days,ATR_14,width=1)
     ax2.xaxis_date()
     pp.savefig()
```

This throws the error.

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Is there a problem if we plot bar chart along with line chart

```
indx    ATR_14  RSI_14
20141015    0.01737336  99.48281325
20141016    0.017723579 99.48281325
20141017    0.020027102 99.53091876
20141020    0.024023488 99.67180924
20141021    0.02415369  99.72027954
20141022    0.026266531 99.76100661
20141023    0.026764327 85.41188977
```

Comment: At what line did you get the TypeError? I would check ATR_14 to see it is what you think it should be.

Comment: @Hun File                                                                         "graph_of_every_stock.py", line 90, in <module>                                                   i didn't understand ATR_14 issue you mention

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I copy and pasted your code with very little modification, and it worked for me using python 3.4. xlabels need some improvement.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data', delimiter='\s+')
days = pd.to_datetime(df['indx'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
RSI_14 = df['RSI_14']
ATR_14 = df['ATR_14']

fig5 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig5.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig5.add_subplot(212)
ax1.plot_date(x=days, y=RSI_14,fmt="ro-",label="ROC_7")
ax2.bar(days,ATR_14,width=1)
ax2.xaxis_date()
plt.show()
```

[image]